# Get second most significant bit of a number

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

You are a C programmer given an integer `i > 1`. Can you write a function `msb2` that returns the second most significant bit of it, in other words:
given a number, what's the bit to the right of the leftmost 1 bit?
I.e in `1011111` it is 0, in `1100000` it is 1.

Not allowed:

- any loops (e.g. checking each of the 64 bits separately)
- floating arithmetic

Allowed are:

- All C integer operators

Is there a constant-time (constant in the number of bits, assuming that all C integer operators take constant time, and assuming that the number of bits is not constant) function for `msb2`?

One idea I head: Given `i`, we know `i & (i >> 1) >= (1<<((int)log2(i)-1)) <=> msb2(i)=1`, however, `log2(i)` can not be computed easily. Maybe this can still be used somehow?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but [these bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) might help.

Comment: I don't understand why this gets down votes and why people say it is unclear. What is unclear?

Comment: I understood it and I have a solution. A better phrasing is probably "Given a number, what's the bit to the right of the leftmost 1 bit? I.e in 1011111 it is 0, in 1100000 it is 1."

Comment: @Jens not bad, at least, you're in log(bitwidth).

Comment: log2(i) can be 1 or 2  cycled on most processors with the CountLeadingZeros (clz) operation.  Most compilers will support it as an intrinsic.  But as this is not allowed, then just do a table lookup of every possible bit pattern.  Lame, but this feels like an interview question anyways.  If too big, break it up into 2 or 4 entries.  Constant time.  Beware to treat 0x01 special as there is no bit to its right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use

```
x > (x ^ (x >> 1))
```

The value `(x ^ (x >> 1))` will start with `11` if `x` starts with `10`, and with `10` if `x` starts with `11`. Thus, the comparison gives exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get at the leftmost 1 bit (see `msb64()`), the rest is easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t msb64(uint64_t x);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint64_t x, msb;

    if (argv[1] && sscanf (argv[1], "%lu", &x) == 1) {
        msb = msb64(x);
        printf ("msb2(%lu) = %d\n", x, x & (msb >> 1) ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return 0;
}

uint64_t msb64(uint64_t x)
{
    x |= (x >> 1);
    x |= (x >> 2);
    x |= (x >> 4);
    x |= (x >> 8);
    x |= (x >> 16);
    x |= (x >> 32);
    return x & ~(x >> 1);
}

$ ./a.out 11
msb2(11) = 0
$ ./a.out 15
msb2(15) = 1
```

Comment: I tried  `msb64(2)` and came up with 2.  Is not `0` expected?  (Sorry about previous errant comment)

Comment: @chux the `msb64` function just returns the msb of `2` (`10`), which is indeed a 1-bit at the second position (`10`), i.e. `2`. The result (`x & (msb >> 1) ? 1 : 0`) is finally 0, as expected.

Comment: @chux This is "constant time" for integer of size at most 64 bits. Hence this is not a general solution. If you have a custom int type for arbitrarily large numbers you can't use this. Look at the accepted answer. That one will always work under the given specs. No assumptions about size of integers made. (Note the "constant in the number of bits, assuming that all C integer operators take constant time, and assuming that the number of bits is not constant" in the description of the task). So I would argue that this actually is not that "nicely done with constant time."

Comment: @dingalapadum  This answer working with a fixed size 64-bit integer is constant time for 64-bit or narrower integers and is readily expanded to any fixed integer width such as `uintmax_t` in fixed time.  C does not specify "int type for arbitrarily large numbers" and neither did OP ask for that but for "integer".  In C, specified integer types are all of fixed width.  The selected answer - which is good- does make an assumption: unsigned integer - which is reasonable.

Comment: @chux: You are wrong. The selected answer does not assume an unsigned integer. The question says "an integer i > 1". The selected answer will also work for signed ints as long as they are >1. For the other part: saying this answer solves the problem in constant time, is like saying "I can sort arrays with at most <put your favourite arbitrarily large constant here> elements in constant time".

Comment: @dingalapadum Agree accepted solution works with signed integer types given OP's "integer `i > 1`".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this *technically* meets the criteria: Write 63 `if` statements (assuming your integers are 64 bits in size), one for each possible solution.  Yes, that basically mimics what a loop would do, but it is still constant time (which the corresponding loop would be, actually, but a tiny bit harder to argue).

Comment: I think it does not, since I did not specify that the number of bits was constant. Now I added it so it gets more clear.

Comment: Scott, would you also think this should be reopened? I believe a few SO folks were too trigger happy here...

Comment: @Johannes: "... checking each of the 64 bits separately)..."  Also, show me a compiler where the size of an integer variable *isn't* constant, but the integer operations take constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Naive log(nbits) thing: (without loops!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned long org , val;

sscanf(argv[1] , "%lx", &org);

val = org ;

if (val >= (2<<16)) val >>= 16;
if (val >= (2<<8)) val >>= 8;
if (val >= (2<<4)) val >>= 4;
if (val >= (2<<2)) val >>= 2;
if (val >= (2<<1)) val >>= 1;
if (val <= 2) val <<= 1; // This is needed for org = 1 ;-)

printf("%lx -> %lx %c\n"
    , org, val, val&1 ? '+' : '-');

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clz` makes this trivial if it exists.  If not, you can compute it constant time as follows.  From this thread:

http://community.arm.com/thread/6400

```
static __INLINE uint32_t __CLZ(uint32_t x) {  
    extern uint8_t const log2Lkup[256];  

    if (x >= 0x00010000U) {  
        if (x >= 0x01000000U) {  
            return 8U - log2Lkup[x >> 24];  
        }  
        else {  
            return 16U - log2Lkup[x >> 16];  
        }  
    }  
    else {  
        if (x >= 0x00000100U) {  
            return 24U - log2Lkup[x >> 8];  
        }  
        else {  
            return 32U - log2Lkup[x];  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The function would need the log2 (binary logarithm) lookup table defined in a .c file:

```
uint8_t const log2Lkup[256] = {  
  0U, 1U, 2U, 2U, 3U, 3U, 3U, 3U, 4U, 4U, 4U, 4U, 4U, 4U, 4U, 4U,  
  5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U, 5U,  
  6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U,  
  6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U, 6U,  
  7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U,  
  7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U,  
  7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U,  
  7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U, 7U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U,  
  8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U, 8U  
};
```

I left the code intact from the website as an example as modifying the table could make this even easier.

To solve your case, take `(32 - clz(x)) - 1` and handle the case where `x` is 1 or 0 specially as it is undefined.  Note: for 64-bit values, just add a few more lookups...

```
int wantedValue(int x)
{
    if(x <= 1) return -1;

    return (int)(32 - __CLZ(x)) - 1;
}
```